# What does it mean to latex `\let\install=y\input{breqn.dtx}`

Tags: packages, installing

I'm trying to install the `breqn` package but have a hard time understanding where I should type what they recommend:  `\let\install=y\input{breqn.dtx}` I use Mac, TeXShop

Actually what they recommend is the following:

```
>  > Unpacking: %    (a) If breqn.ins is present: %           tex breqn.ins
>     > %    (b) Without breqn.ins: %           tex breqn.dtx %    (c) If you
>     > insist on using LaTeX %           latex
>     > \let\install=y\input{breqn.dtx} %        (quote the arguments
>     > according to the demands of your shell)
```

I cannot find breqn.ins and I use PdfLatex (I think) hence I'm trying to do the (c)-option.

Comment: Are you sure you have to install this way? Do you use `MacTeX`? I think that will be able to install a package for you instead of going manually through the extraction and installation process

Comment: I have TeXLive 2015 if that's what you mean

Comment: I guess the question I should ask is how to make an sty file from a dtx file, it's been asked before with horrible answers though :(

Comment: If you have a full texlive installation, breqn is already included. If you only have texlive basic use the texlive manager to install breqn

Comment: Issuing `\let\install=y` propbably just skips the confirmation step involved when installing a package manually. Like others have said though, you likely already have `breqn`. If you don't, you should be installing it with `$ tlmgr install breqn`.